# How create a message protocol

Tags: python, web-services, protocols

So I have to create a message protocol that works like this:

```
codFunc arg1 arg2...
```

ex:

```
0 'hello world'
10 'user' 'password'
```

Right now I concatenate to send, and use `string.split` to read, but for several reasons, that is not the best way.

So my question is, what's the best way to create the protocol? What existing protocols should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: The "right way" to represent PDUs (protocol data units) would be to use a real marshalling format like ASN.1, Pickle, or Protocol Buffers. But if your protocol only needs to handle single-line messages composed of an integer followed by a set of strings, something like csv or what you already listed (space-separated values) would be sufficient.  But message format is only half the job - you still need to define the protocol itself (the sequence of allowed messages between participants).

Comment: Depending on how large your messages are, you may want to look into compressing them before they're sent and decompressing them when you receive them on the other end.  You'll also likely want to encrypt the messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shlex is probably good, split has problems with quoted whitespace, pickle is insecure.  JSON is good.

I like to use:
https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=bufsock
...with ASCII data that's null terminated or something, to anchor parts of the protocol.

Bear in mind that there's not always a one to one relationship between send()'s and recv()'s.  It's easy to get complacent about this, but it can cause reliability problems under network load.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with split is that if your username contains white-space, it will be splited into separate arguments.

Split it one time to get responsible function number:

```
num, args = s.split(None, 1)
```

Parse string into arguments, maybe with [`shlex`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html):

```
import shlex
argv = shlex.split(args)
```

Remove surrounding quotes:

```
argv = [s.strip(shlex.quotes) for s in argv]
```

Call your function:

```
myfunc(*argv)
```